# Data from datatable only populating one column in ListView with C# Winforms

Tags: winforms, listview, datatable

I have a datatable that I have populated from an Access database that has table name, "codes" and 3 columns, "CodeNum", "TableName" and "Desc". In my Winforms C# app, I would like to populate a ListView with this datatable and have it show columns(with column names) in same format. I have tried numerous code combinations, but cannot get this to work. The code below shows CodeNum and TableName data in 1st column, not DESC data and does not show column name(CodeNum). Any help greatly appreciated. Don't really need, 
"DataRowState.Deleted" if statement but works same way when it is commented out.

Listview should have 3 columns with data listed in each column.

Thank you.

```
        //Get data from Access database and populate datatable "dt"
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection();
        string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=M:\gendoc\Codes.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        ListViewItem LItem1 = new ListViewItem();
        Conn.ConnectionString = conn;
        Conn.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Codes order by CodeNum", Conn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        Conn.Close();


        // Clear the ListView control
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        int ColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
        //Add columns
        for (int k = 0; k < ColCount; k++)
        {
            listView1.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName);
        }
        // Display items in the ListView control
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow drow = dt.Rows[i];

            // Only row that have not been deleted
            if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                // Define the list items
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow[0].ToString());
                for (int j = 1; j < ColCount; j++)
                {
                    string g = drow[j].ToString();
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow[j].ToString());
                }
                // Add the list items to the ListView
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code works.  Maybe call `listView1.Columns.Clear()` too since it isn't clear where you are calling this code.

Comment: Thanks for response LarsTech. In the main form load event I am showing the form:

Comment: CodeList CL = new CodeList();
CL.Show();

Comment: The posted code doesn't reproduce the problem though. I have a DataTable with three columns and a couple rows and the ListView control populates correctly using your code.

Comment: Is the datatable correct? I checked, and it adds 3 columns to the ListView. It's as if the ListView doesn't recognize it. All the variations of code I have tried only populate 1 column with data. Is there something I need to specify with the ListView to enable multiple columns? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have the ListView control in `View = View.Details;` mode?

Comment: I think I got it. Right click on Listview, properties, View, change option to Details(It was Tile and I tried others but not this one). I thought it was something simple I missed, I probably should have known this.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Listview, properties, View, change option to Details